# How to get the coordinates of the mouse inside a relatively positioned element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to position an element `$menu` on the mouse's pointer (on click). `$menu` is inside `$icon` which has `position: relative`. (`$menu` has position absolute.)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function(ev) {
    var $icon = $(ev.currentTarget)
    var $menu = $icon.next()
    var thisPos = $icon.position()
    var x = ev.clientX
    var y = ev.clientY
    $menu.css('top', y + 'px')
    $menu.css('left', x + 'px')
  });
})
```

```css
nav > ul[_v-2e9e2f12] {
  background: #3a3c3a;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  box-shadow: 2px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

nav > ul li[_v-2e9e2f12] {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 8px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #ccc;
}

ul[_v-0078ee36] {
  background: #3a3c3a;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

a[_v-2e9e2f12] {
  display: block;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul _v-2e9e2f12="">
    <li _v-2e9e2f12="">
      <a _v-2e9e2f12="">
      </a>
      <ul _v-0078ee36="" _v-2e9e2f12="">
        Hello!
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li _v-2e9e2f12="">
      <a _v-2e9e2f12="">
      </a>
      <ul _v-0078ee36="" _v-2e9e2f12="">
        Hello!
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

But I get a weird behavior: `$menu` is not positioned on the mouse's pointer but a few pixels to the right and bottom. And for the second element it's even worse: many pixels to the right and bottom.

How to fix this, and make `$menu` to be positioned right in the mouse's pointer?

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9jm82cb/2/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `offsetX` and `offsetY` instead of `client`'s

```
var x = ev.offsetX;
var y = ev.offsetY;
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/d9jm82cb/4/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Why does it work with `offset` and not with `client`?

Comment: @alexchenco clientX and clientY will give you the coordinates by considering the view port whereas offsetX and offsetY will give you the coordinates by considering the element that you have clicked.